# Is there are reason against a getLatestFrom OperatorFunction for ngrx effects?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

To access state in an ngrx effect, we can use withLatestFrom like this (taken from the documentation https://ngrx.io/guide/effects):

```
this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess),
        concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
          withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds)))
        )),
        tap(([action, bookCollection]) => {
          if (bookCollection.length === 1) {
            window.alert('Congrats on adding your first book!');
          } else {
            window.alert('You have added book number ' + bookCollection.length);
          }
        })
      )
```

This effect, like many effects in my application, does not actually access the `action` parameter from the list that we get by using `withLatestFrom` but is only interested in the `bookCollection`. So I was wondering, why not simply do this:

```
function getLatestFrom<T, R>(observable: Observable<T>) {
    return concatMap((action: R) => of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(observable),
        map(([, value]) => value)
    ))
}
```

and replace the above snippet with

```
this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess),
        getLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds))),
        tap(bookCollection => {
          if (bookCollection.length === 1) {
            window.alert('Congrats on adding your first book!');
          } else {
            window.alert('You have added book number ' + bookCollection.length);
          }
        })
      )
```

This looks much cleaner to me, but I haven't found anything like this anywhere, so I was wondering if there is a reason against doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> but is only interested in the bookCollection

rather than using `withLatestFrom` operator which returns an array of results from both source and input Observables, you might be better with `switchMapTo` which returns result from input observable only, as demonstrated below:

*SwitchMapTo*

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess),
  switchMapTo(this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds), first())),
  tap(bookCollection => {})
)
```

**VS**
*WithLatestFrom*

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds))),
  tap(([action, bookCollection]) => {})
)
```

Comment: this would be equivalent to `switchMap(() => (this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds))),`, correct? The problem with that approach is that everything happening inside the tap will then also be executed when `this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds))` emits a new value and not only if the `CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess` action is triggered again

Comment: this isn't a problem since you can use either `take` or `first` operators:  `switchMapTo(this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds), first()))`

Comment: so I could replace my function with the following, correct?
`return switchMapTo(observable.pipe(first()))`
is there any difference in behaviour between that solution and the one described in the ngrx documentation?